# Return control from external command to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cordova

I'm doing a batch file to unify all the Phonegap commands to create an app. All seems work well, but after the command `phonegap create appName` my cmd stops the batch script and doesn't continue working. I suppose that Phonegap's commands finish with an "exit" or similar, but I'm not sure.

Does someone know if there is any way to run this commands in a batch file without this problem? Is there any way to return the control to the batch script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
call phonegap create appName
```

Comment: Thank you! I though that `call' was only for custom .bat

Comment: The same applies to [cordova build windows].   This answer suggesting the use of "call" fixes that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using [`CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to start Google Chrome then immediately return control to the console, but it wasn't returning to the console. (Windows 7, not in command prompt but using a *.cmd file)

I solved the case by using [`START`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```