# CMD closes after calling cordova command

Tags: cordova, batch-file, ionic-framework

I want to write a batch file which creates a release apk for my ionic projects.

- copy the project folder to release folder -> works
- change directory --> works
- execute: "cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console" --> Works but CMD window closes after that.

  ```
  XCOPY %project% %release% /S /E /C /H /O /R /Y /D /V

  cd %release%

  cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
  -- exits the window after this command --

  cordova build --release android
  ```

Any idea about that?

Comment: Try `start "" /WAIT "cordova ..."`

Comment: does not work "cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console" was not found

Comment: Sorry, remove the quotes around the `cordova` command line and try again: `start "" /WAIT cordova ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

found the answer in a phonegap thread [Return control from external command to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182743/return-control-from-external-command-to-a-batch-file)

command is:

```
call cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
...
```

Comment: If cordova is a batch file then you need to use CALL, but START /WAIT should work as well.

Comment: In my case `START /WAIT` is not working, but `call` seems to be working